# Audio transmission via Webrtc pricking when overused CPU

Tags: audio, webrtc

I'm transmitting from an outdated computer (AMD A6-5400K and 8GB of RAM) and the transmission is stable when the computer is not interacting, but when, for example, I open a Chrome tab, the graphics look like this:

Processing:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bytes received:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Jitter:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As you can see, the processing was to the maximum, and at that moment I hear a kind of perforation in the transmission.
Of course the problem is also in the computer, but my big doubt here is that using other transmission software (that use the UDP protocol) I do not hear this prick, that is, even with the processing at the peak it remains stable and I would like to reproduce the same thing with Webrtc.

Comment: So you want stable encoding with irregular/limited cpu?

Comment: @DirkV Not necessarily stable, but I would like to work around it in a way that is not so noticeable.

Comment: Well webrtc is udp already. But if the process just has no cpu available I don't think you can expect it to work. Unless you give your application complete cpu privilege and suppress other applications cpu usage